# Can't log into ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04

So i have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS all the updates are installed and the OS has been working perfectly. Until today. I can't log into my own account, I put in the password correctly, the screen fades for a minute and then it kicks me back to login. I've tried rebooting, some grub fixes, and several other things I've found on the site but so far none have worked. I really don't want to have to reinstall the entire OS.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Press Ctrl+Alt+F1 to leave graphical environment. Can you login there? (When entering the password, you'll see nothing, not even stars)

Comment: yup, but its still a dos screen.

Comment: so I can't actually log onto my profile

Answer (score 0):

In case you are unable to login press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> , this starts the virtual terminal, try logging in there, if it works then type `sudo lightdm start`
then you will your GUI back.

Comment: tried it, with no luck. It just shows me a blank black screen for 10 minutes and kicks me back to log in.